# Raw Data Transformation - messy price file

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I have fairly messy file that I need to transform for something more usefull. Any idea's how could it be done in excel, sql, tableau, talend anything...

### Raw Data

*Linecode,Product Name,Price Valid from,Price Valid From Year,Price Valid From Month,Price Valid to,Price Valid To Month,Valid To Year,Price

ABC111,Pro Name A,11/12/2012,2012,12,07/05/2013,5,2013,£11.00

ABC111,Pro Name A,08/05/2013,2013,5,09/05/2013,5,2013,£11.00

ABC111,Pro Name A,08/05/2013,2013,5,31/12/9999,12,9999,£12.00

ABC111,Pro Name A,10/05/2013,2013,5,31/12/9999,12,9999,£12.00

ABC111,Pro Name A,28/10/2013,2013,10,31/12/9999,12,9999,£12.00*

### 2013 Price

*Linecode,Product Name,Price,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec

ABC111,Pro Name A, £11.00, £11.00, £11.00, £11.00, £11.00, £12.00, £12.00, £12.00, £12.00, £12.00, £12.00, £12.00, £12.00*

Comment: I prefer the format in the raw data.  But what you want to do is called "pivoting", which is something that all the tools you mention should be able to do.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are looking for for output?  "Something more useful" could mean anything.

Comment: I find this confusing because you have the same item having its price redefined as an identical price repeatedly in spite of the price validity remaining the same.  Does this happen in your actual data?

Comment: Well it's not really pivoting. If i do pivot it is only going to show me price in one month. not throughout the year. I need to reflect in my other file price increase, For example if we done price increase on one product in June we would get first 6 months for old price, which i would link with my sold cases, and then next 6 months with new price. so basically i need to sort of duplicate data. By something useful I mean "2013 price". Yes Myles it would happen as they might be product spec changes which would create new line with same price